# Something is going wrong with url's

Tags: bolt-cms

In my header and footer template I have links like `/pagina/test`.

This works, but on other pages Bolt generates links like `pagina/pagina/test`. What am I doing wrong here?

To prevent wrong links I type in the whole url now `www.test.nl/pagina/test`, but this is not an ideal situation.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I 'd say that you'd forgotten the first slash, but since you've specifically stated that you put that one in...

Could you post a more complete chunk of code?